# NG8003: error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular11

I got an issue No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm' on my first project angular 11. I'm already import FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts but I still get this error.
Here's my code:

This my product.component.html code :

```
 <form #tambahBuku='ngForm' (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addBook.value)">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Title Book :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-5" name=title placeholder="Title Book">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Author :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-5" name=author placeholder="Book Author">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Price :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-5" name=price placeholder="Book Price">             
          </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

this my product.component.ts code

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  onSubmit(data){
    alert ("book "+data.title+'submited')
  }
}
```

and this my app.module.ts code

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// Material design
import { MaterialDesign } from './material/material.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ProductComponent is declared in a different FeatureModule and not directly in AppModule then this module will also need to import FormsModule.

Comment: Thanks you for your help, the issue is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Product component is not declared in the AppModule where you imported the required 'FormsModule'. You ned to import this 'FormsModule' in the module where your Product component is declared.